# Create a writeable overlay from inside docker, without using tmpfs?

Tags: docker, overlayfs

I would like to create a new writable overlay from within a docker container. As the root filesystem in docker is already an overlay, it can't be used as the upperdir of another overlay. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67198603/overlayfs-inside-docker-container) suggests using tmpfs for the upperdir, and this works for me. However, I need to write more data than will fit in RAM, and this container has no swap space.

How can I create a writable overlay which is not limited by physical RAM?

I am far from an expert in Linux/Unix, so feel free to explain the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a writable overlay like this is inside of docker can be quite tricky.

One option you have is to use a volume or bind mount into the container. Inside the container these will not be an overlay so their respective directory can be used as an upper. That of course has a trip hazard if accidentally sharing the volume or failing to delete it after.

Another option is to manually a file as a loopback

- truncate or fallocate a new file
- mkfs.ext4
- mount -o loop

Comment: Good clear answer! I'll accept this as it's a general solution although it didn't work for my situation. I can't use the first suggestion because I can't control how the container is launched, it's part of a Gitlab CI system. The manual loopback suggestion works initially but I notice it's modifying state on the host's device table which is not really suitable. I'm really surprised it's not possible to create and use a loop device entirely within the container without special permissions from the host.

Comment: @Roofus yes there's no device namespace in Linux (yet). I read somewhere that Linus Torvalds dislikes the need for loopback device and that the block layer cannot be passed through from the filesystem. But I don't know how true or current that was so I wouldn't hold your breath.